# Pass Generic Object To Function And Get Intellisense

Tags: c#, generics, types

I would like to be able to pass a known type to a general function but I'm getting compile errors because I can't cast the type at design time.

Consider my OnCreate function:

EXAMPLE 1:

```
private void OnCreate<T>(T object)
{
   object.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
       object.SpecialProperty = "Hello";
}
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
private void OnCreate<T>(T object)
{
   object.BirthDate = DateTime.Now;
       object.BirthdayMessage = "Happy Birthday";
}
```

I want to call OnCreate and pass to it an object. That object happens to be a model object in an MVC application. I can't predict what model object is being passed to OnCreate yet I want to access the unique properties of the model that is passed. As my examples show above, one model has a CurrentDate and a SpecialProperty property; another has a BirthDate and a BirthdayMessage property. I don't want to create a special function for each because I have many different models. Also, this OnCreate function is going to get inherited from a base class. The idea here is to provide a "hook" into the controller's Create method so that someone can alter the model properties before they are persisted to the database. In other words, the controller's Create method would pass the model to my OnCreate function, then some work would be done on the model before it's passed back.

As you would expect, each model has different properties. Due to this requirement, I realize that I won't be able to early-bind and get intellisense with the OnCreate function--but my problem is that the compiler won't let me refer to properties of the object until it knows the object type. I can't cast it at design-time because I don't know the type until run-time.

**EDIT**

I think my question wasn't so clear, judging by the answers (for which I'm grateful--they're just not what I'm looking for). Perhaps it's better to show how I want to call OnCreate():

```
OnCreate(model);
```

Now, when OnCreate receives object "model", it needs to be able to set properties on that model. I suppose I could use reflection on the model and do something like this (this is pseudocode only--still learning about reflection):

```
if typeof(model) is CustomerModel then
   (CustomerModel(model)).BirthDate = "1/1/1960";
   (CustomerModel(model)).BirthdayMessage = "Happy Birthday";
elseif typeof(model) is AnotherModel then
   (AnotherModel(model)).CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
   (AnotherModel(model)).SpecialProperty = "Hello";
etc...
```

But I am trying to avoid having a bunch of if/then statements. I prefer if the call could be "routed" to a function that's specific for the type being passed. That way, the call to OnCreate would send the object to an overload(?) so that no reflection logic is needed...

**SECOND EDIT**

Upon further reflection (no pun intended), I don't think having a bunch of if/else statements in the OnCreate function is the best approach here. I came up with another idea that might work best and accommodates my expressed wish to "avoid having a bunch of if/then statements" (specified in my first Edit): The idea is to have my models implement IOnCreate, which would provide the .OnCreate() method. Thus, my "generic" model objects that implement IOnCreate could be used this way:

```
model.OnCreate();
```

Then the OnCreate function would know what properties are on the model:

```
public void OnCreate()
{
    this.BirthdayMessage = "Happy Birthday";
    etc...
}
```

I just see two issues here:

1 - In the controller I would need to test that the model implements IOnCreate--if it doesn't, I wouldn't try to call OnCreate().
2 - I need to be sure that adding a public function such as OnCreate() will not interfere with how EF6 generates database tables in a code-first project.

My question now is whether this approach be best... or whether there is any other idea to consider...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you have some models with some common properties but no common layer (Interface / Class) in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

Since `T` is *any type*, compiler can't expect it having `CurrentDate` or `SpecialProperty`;
you could try solving the problem like that:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
  DateTime CurrentDate {get; set}
  String SpecialProperty {get; set}
}

public class MyClassA: IMyInterface {...}

public class MyClassB: IMyInterface {...}

public class MyClassC: IMyInterface {...}

...

private void OnCreate<T>(T value)
  where T: IMyInterface // <- T should implement IMyInterface
{
  value.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
  value.SpecialProperty = "Hello";
}
```

Comment: private void OnCreate(IMyInterface value) { ... } // :)

Comment: @DragonFire: Well, your code is better in this case (to set two properties), but the question is about generics, so in the answer I've left generic

Comment: @DmitryBychenko classes don't have common properties as mentioned in the  question.that doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: As Selman22 said, I can't rely on common properties and the properties I need are not on the "object" object.

Answer (score 0):

By your example it seems unlikely the `Generics` are the the solution for you problem (your app), it would seems that a use of an abstract layer (`Interface` or `Abstract Class`) is more appropriate.

When using "bare bone" generics any Type can be passed to your method, now since any type in .Net is of type `Object` you can execute any object related functionality on those generics parameters. To extend this ability of the generics to implements the most basic type in the inheritance hierarchy we have [Generics Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx), those allow you to limit the range of types that can be passed as a generic argument. In your case you'd want to use `Type Constraints`, which limit the range of types to only those which implement the type specified.

For example, we have type `A`, and the `A` has types `B` and `C` as derived classes, we want method `M` to accept only type how implements `A`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        M(new A()); // will work
        M(new B()); // will work
        M(new C()); // will work
        M(new D()); // wont work
    }

    public static string M<T>(T arg)
        where T : A
    {
        return arg.Data;
    }
}

public class A { public string Data { get; set; } }
public class B : A { }
public class C : B { }
public class D { }
```

### Edit

According to your last edit it would seems that you have two options to solve this problem.

Implementing an abstraction layer (an `Interface`): You may want to add an interface and implement it by your models.

```
public static void OnCreate(IBirthable arg)
{
    arg.BirthDate = ...;
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IBirthable
{
    DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    string BirthdayMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Models:

```
public class CustomerModel : IBirthable
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BirthdayMessage { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherModel : IBirthable
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BirthdayMessage { get; set; }
}
```

---

Using [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): If you choose not to use an interface, perhaps is has no logical connection with your models you may want use reflection.

```
public static void OnCreate<T>(T arg)
{
        var type = arg.GetType();
        var birthDateProperty = type.GetProperty("BirthDate");
        if (birthDateProperty == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument not is implementing the model");
        birthDateProperty.SetValue(arg, DateTime.Now);
        //And so on...
}
```

Models:

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BirthdayMessage { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BirthdayMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: public static string M(A arg) { ... } // ;))))

Comment: @DragonFire you right, as I mentioned at the begging, is seems that abstraction is the way to do this.

Comment: I think this discussion is getting to far into generics. I'm trying to solve a problem that might not have generics as a solution. Please see my edited question. Thank you for participating.